# Prove by induction that $d_n=2^n+3^n$, where $d_n = 5d_{n-1}-6d_{n-2}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, induction

I have one more induction question.
$d_0 =2 $ $d_1=5$

let $d_n=5d_{n-1} - 6d_{n-2}$

Prove that $d_n=2^n+3^n$

Comment: What are the values $d_0$ and $d_1$?

Comment: Yes, without knowing $d_0$ and $d_1$, this statement is not true. Or at least, without knowing some pair of values.

Comment: NB. Not every question asking for a proof fits in the [tag:proof-writing] and [tag:proof-strategy] tags.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming $d_0=2$ and $d_1=5$ (which also starts the induction, incidentally):
let $n \geq 2$, and suppose the property holds for all $0\leq k< n$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
d_{n} &= 5d_{n-1} - 6d_{n-2} \\
&= 5\left(2^{n-1}+3^{n-1}\right) - 6\left(2^{n-2}+3^{n-2}\right) \qquad\qquad\text{(induction hypothesis)} \\
&= 5\cdot 2^{n-1}+5\cdot 3^{n-1} - 3\cdot 2^{n-1}- 2\cdot 3^{n-1} \\
&= 2\cdot 2^{n-1}+3\cdot 3^{n-1} \\
&= 2^{n}+3^{n} 
\end{align*}
$$
so by induction, the property holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Just for completeness, this is another (standard) method for such recurrence relations, which does not rely on induction but rather on a systematic, generic method:

 * The characteristic polynomial of your recurrence relation $d_{n+2}-5d_{n+1}+6d_n$ is $X^2-5X+6$;

 * This polynomial has two _distinct_ roots $a=2$, $a=3$;
 * General solutions of the recurrence relation are therefore (with coefficients $\alpha,\beta$ depending on the initial conditions $d_0$, $d_1$) of the form:
$$
d_n = \alpha\cdot a^n + \beta\cdot b^n
$$
Here, plugging $d_0=2$, $d_1=5$ yields $\alpha=\beta=1$.